# Spring 3.2 Redirect is not working:Getting Error 405

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a welcome.jsp which has signUp link when it is clicked javascript function showSignUp is called which invokes controller and controller should redirect it to the signUp form(signup.jsp).But redirect is not happening and I am getting Error 405 Method Not Found.(Controller call is happening I am able to print sysout "In ShowSignUp method" )

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<body>
<a href="javascript:signupObj.showSignup ();" >SignUP</a>
</body>
```

**signup.js**

```
var signupObj  = {
        showSignup : function() {
                $.ajax({

                    url: "showSignup",
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert("sucessful");
                    }
                });
        }
    };
```

**Controller Class**

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/showSignup")
    public String showSignup(HttpServletRequest httprequest,HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        System.out.println("In ShowSignUp method");
        return "redirect:signup";
    }
```

**Signup.jsp**

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="javascript:signupObj.signup()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username : </td>
<td><input  id="username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password :</td>
<td><input id="password"/></td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



</form>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

     <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Does the controller class has a `@RequestMapping` which has `method` set to POST?

Comment: no i havent specified the method to post in controller

Comment: Can you show the complete controller with the mapping to `signup`?

Comment: I have a signup.jsp There is no mapping for signup

Comment: /showSignup page should redirected to signup.jsp page

Comment: Please show full stacktrace ...

Comment: console : In ShowSignUp method

Answer (score 0):

You can return just view name without redirect like this:

```
return "Signup";
```

Comment: Yes I know that But My Question was why redirect is not working

Comment: @user3745727 Are you handling the `submit` using ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

> But redirect is not happening and I am getting Error 405 Method Not
>   Found

You are using `ajax` call in your application  and i dont understand why you need to redirect it to another page . the purpose of ajax is to update the part of a page.

```
    return "redirect:signup";
```

As you redirect it to `signup` have you handled it with another request mapping url like this,

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/signup",,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSignup(HttpServletRequest httprequest,HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        System.out.println("In ShowSignUp method");
        return "View Name Here";
    }
```

<sub>Remember you should follow P-R-G pattern once you redirect</sub>